# Handle automated post installation setup

Tags: setuptools

I'm running a post installation setup after installing a new linux distro. Currently not all of these steps can be automated because they have circular dependencies which I would like to resolve.

These are the tools onvolved

- A public Git repo with a basic installation script for packages and system settings, this is cloned manually and then run
- Some private Git repos with more sensitive information for setup which require an SSH key to clone
- Credentials and SSH keys are managed via Keepass
- The Keepass database is stored and synced across devices via Dropbox

What I have been doing so far

- Clone the public repo and run the setup script (which will install Dropbox and Keepass)
- Login to Dropbox to be able to get access to the Keepass database (manual)
- Get the SSH keys from Keepass and use them to clone the private git repos (manual)

Anyone got any ideas how to automate the whole thing without needing to do any manual steps?

So the step that is quite manual is getting the private repos cloned and executed as they require an SSH key for access ehich is only available after Docker account login and accessing the database with keepass as the ssh key is stored in there.

The login with docker is the tricky one as it needs login via a browser through their CLI.

Is there a way to automate this in a better way (I'm open to switching my setup around as well)?